# Replacing Hard disk Causing "Boot Device Not Found"

Tags: hard-drive, bios, operating-systems, bootable-media, diskpart

My HP Laptop hard disk died

I decided to use an old Hoshiba laptop hard disk to replace the died one

I installed the HDD into the laptop

I turn the laptop on I get this Error

```
Boot Device Not Found

Please Install an operating system on your hard disk

Hard Disk (3F0)

F2 System Diagnostics
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsj3p.jpg)

I had a USB with windows repair

though it I got into diskpart

```
DISKPART> list disk

Disk ###  Status      Size     Free   Dyn    Gpt
--------  ------      ------   -----  ---    ---
Disk 0    Online      465 GB    0 GB  
Disk 1    Online       15 GB    0 GB 

DISKPART> select disk 0
DISKPART> list volume

Volume ###  Ltr   Label          Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---   ------------   -----  -----       -------  -------    -----
Volume 0    C     System Rese    NTFS    Partition  100 MB    Healthy
Volume 1    E                    NTFS    Partition  244 GB    Healthy
Volume 2    F                    NTFS    Partition  221 GB    Healthy
Volume 3    D     EDS-USB        NTFS    Removable   15 GB    Healthy
```

note no starts on Dyn nor Gpt

Is there a way i can run my HP laptop on this HDD?
Can I keep data on the HDD installed and OS and the OS Image partition?

Thanks

Comment: The new and the old laptops have entirely different boot modes (See BIOS vs UEFI) so no, the old one won't boot in the new one. While using another computer you can backup the old personal files but that's it. In order to use the old drive in the new computer you'll have to install the OS from scratch.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: If that were the problem, they could activate BIOS emulation (CSM) or use one of many existing "Convert Windows MBR/BIOS disk to GPT/UEFI" tutorials on this site.

Comment: @grawity Yes, you're technically correct and I also hesitated when posting the first comment. In the end I decided to suggest what's best for the OP. Trying to boot an old OS installed for an entirely different hardware, let alone  BIOS/MBR installation in a new UEFI machine, is a **very bad idea**.

Comment: i turned out for the best. i formatted the hard disk and removed all partitions, and through Windows Repair USB i managed to install windows 10. surprisingly I was activated!!!!!!! I dont know how and that was a surprise to me as I did not enter any Windows Keys !!! could it be Windows got the BIOS or any other hardware info and checked in their online OEM data bases and activated it??